# How can I update a text frame in Scribus from a text file

Tags: text-editing, scribus

I'm using Scribus for an instruction manual translated into several languages. Is there a way to update a text frame, which was already filled by "Get text..." from a plain text file, without loosing all the  applied style settings?
The problem is: I often get small updates (corrected words, improved) in the text files from the translators.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

This is a well known problem, but i am sorry to tell you that it is "officially not" possible at the moment. Check the official bug report of SCRIBUS if you dont believe me: http://bugs.scribus.net/view.php?id=1791

Nevertheless there is a non-trivial procedere to do this. Check this link for more information: [How can I autopopulate text in Scribus from a text file](https://superuser.com/questions/550770/how-can-i-autopopulate-text-in-scribus-from-a-text-file)